# GWT getting missing-plugins message

Tags: gwt

When i tried to run an GWT sample application i got a missing-plugins on firefox (or Chrome) it seems that i'm missingg something just dont know what to do in order to make it works...

any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html):

> In the development mode window you
>   will find the URL for the local
>   server. Paste this URL into Firefox,
>   Internet Explorer, Chrome, or Safari.
>   Since this is your first time hitting
>   the development mode server, it will
>   prompt you to install the Google Web
>   Toolkit Developer Plugin. Follow the
>   instructions in the browser to install
>   the plugin. Once the Google Web
>   Toolkit Developer Plugin is installed
>   in your browser, navigate to the URL
>   again and the starter application will
>   load in development mode.